# I have multiple tabs on my page and I want the first tab open be default every time users come to that page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

So, on my page I have 3 tabs, **Quick Start**, **FAQ's** and **Support Docs**. I would like so that when ever anyone comes to that page the **Quick start** is automatically open.

Also when they click another tab the Quick start goes away. It doesn't stay on the top, while the other information from the other tab goes underneath it.

**Example:** You come to this page and the tabs are there and Quick start is automatically open showing its content.

```
 **Quick start**         **FAQ**           **Support Docs**
 blah blah balh
 blah blah blah
```

Then you click say you click on **FAQ**

```
 **Quick start**         **FAQ**           **Support Docs**
                        blah blah blah
```

FAQ info shows and quick start info goes away. If someone could please help me with that I would be appreciative. I've added all the codes below. Please HELP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>

ul.tab {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 100px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

/* Float the list items side by side */
ul.tab li {float: left;}

/* Style the links inside the list items */
ul.tab li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
    border: 2px solid #f7931c;
    margin-left: 70px;

}

/* Change background color of links on hover */
ul.tab li a:hover {
    background-color: #f7931c;
    color: #ffffff;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
ul.tab li a:focus, .active {
    background-color: #f7931c;
    color: #ffffff;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
</style>
<body>

<ul class="tab">
  <li class="active"><a href="#" class="tablinks"  onclick="openCity(event,    'quick-start')">Quick Start</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event,  'faq')">FAQ</a>   </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'suport-   docs')">Support Docs</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="quick-start" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Assembly & Setup</h3>
<iframe width="560" height="315"     src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NSnubfVZLSA" frameborder="0"     allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <h3>How it Works</h3>
<iframe width="560" height="315"     src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0unrtD22w38" frameborder="0"     allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>


<div id="faq" class="tabcontent">
  <head>
<style>
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #f7931c;
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 0px;
    display: none;
   background-color: white;
}

div.panel.show {
    display: block !important;
}



<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
  }
}
</script>



<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace("  active",       "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";

   }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: UPDATE: As of now when users come to that page it is just the 3 tabs with nothing showing. Until they click on a tab. Again I want the first TAB just to be open when they get there whether it's the first time or 5th time

Answer (score 0):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/ubgzx29r/6/)**.

You have to show the quick start container by default so you could add inline style for this :

```
<div id="quick-start" class="tabcontent" style="display:block">
```

Or you could also use javascript for this by clicking the tab on ready function :

```
$(function(){
     $('.tablinks:eq(0)').click();
})
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #f7931c;
}

div.tabcontent {
    padding: 0 0px;
    display: none;
   background-color: white;
}

div.tabcontent.active{
    display: block !important;
}


ul.tab {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 100px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

/* Float the list items side by side */
ul.tab li {float: left;}

/* Style the links inside the list items */
ul.tab li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
    border: 2px solid #f7931c;
    margin-left: 70px;

}

/* Change background color of links on hover */
ul.tab li a:hover ,ul.tab li a.active{
    background-color: #f7931c;
    color: #ffffff;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
</style>
       <ul class="tab">
      <li><a href="#quick-start" class="tablinks active">Quick Start</a></li>
      <li><a href="#faq" class="tablinks">FAQ</a></li>
      <li><a href="#cityName" class="tablinks">Support Docs</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="quick-start" class="tabcontent active">
      <h3>Assembly & Setup</h3>
    <iframe width="560" height="315"     src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NSnubfVZLSA" frameborder="0"     allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <h3>How it Works</h3>
    <iframe width="560" height="315"     src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0unrtD22w38" frameborder="0"     allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>


    <div id="faq" class="tabcontent"> lksajbfvlskjdbfbmklsdlfk bmjn </div>
    <div id="cityName" class="tabconte`enter code here`nt">
    kijbdvskj bvksbvk b
    </div>
<script>
function initTabs(){
var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
            register_tab(tabs[i]);
   }
}

function register_tab(tab){
     tab.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var href = tab.href.split('#')[1];
            var panel = document.querySelector('#' + href);
            resetTabs();
            addClass(tab,'active');
            addClass(panel,'active');
        });
}

function resetTabs(){
var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
      var href = tabs[i].href.split('#')[1];
      var panel = document.getElementById(href);
     removeClass(panel,'active');
     removeClass(tabs[i],'active');
   }
}

function addClass(el, className) {
    if (el.classList)
        el.classList.add(className)
    else if (!hasClass(el, className))
        el.className += " " + className
}

function removeClass(el, className) {
    if (el.classList)
        el.classList.remove(className)
    else if (hasClass(el, className)) {
        var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + className + '(\\s|$)')
        el.className = el.className.replace(reg, ' ')
    }
}

initTabs();
</script>
```

I hope this is what you asked for.
check this js fiddle out https://jsfiddle.net/httsggkh/ for working example